# How to install Brother HL-3170CDW printer wirelessly in ubuntu

Tags: wireless, drivers, printing, brother

I am having a difficult time trying to get a new Brother HL-3170CDW printer working in Ubuntu as a wireless printer. I've verified that the printer is visible at 192.168.1.132, and despite entering the printer as lpd://192.168.1.132/BINARY_P1 when adding the printer, any test pages sent are claiming that there's no connection made.

I've installed the printer using both the linux-brprinter-installer-2.0.0.1 (under su), and manually adding the packages hl3170cdwcupswrapper-1.1.2-1.i386.deb and hl3170cdwlpr-1.1.2-1.i386.deb, but no luck in either case.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.10, 64-bit, which may be the issue. However, I can't seem to find 64-bit drivers for this printer for Ubuntu.

---

EDIT: typo.

Comment: Follow the instructions here. They worked for me in Fedora and they should be good for Ubuntu as well. http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadhowto.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=hl3170cdw_all&os=127&dlid=dlf006893_000&flang=4&type3=625

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get the brother HL-3170CDW to print wirelessly in Ubuntu. I first configure the printer to print wirelessly and tested with Windows 7 and iOS.

Through the printer menu I printed the configuration settings to get the IP address of the printer.  I followed the *Add Printer* wizzard and expanded network Printer. It auto-detected the Brother printer through Wi-Fi. I then clicked forward to search for drivers. Accepted the GutenPrint option. Press forward. Selected Brother for the vendor. Press forward. Selected HL-4070CDW (HL-3170CDW was not listed). Choose the BR-Scrip3 driver. Press forward. Choose two trays. Cancel test print.  Go to properties for the printer. Change URI from `lpd://BRW90489AD832C6/BINARY_P1` to `lpd://<IPAdreess>/BINARY_P1`.

Comment: This helped me install the same printer in Arch Linux, thanks! After installing foomatic I did not see HL-3170CDW in the model list. The "Brother HL-4070CDW BR-Script3 (color, 2-sided printing)" works well, and I did not even have to modify the URI.